# Beamer - Uncover within Equation Mode

Tags: beamer, equations

I have an equation and I would like to uncover part of it at a time.  Take y = 2x + 3.

```
\begin{equation*}
y = 2x + 3
\end{equation*}
```

I would like to uncover the 3

```
\begin{equation*}
y = 2x + \uncover<2->{3}
\end{equation*}
```

That syntax for uncover does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Have you tried using \pause instead of \uncover? Or does that not fulfill your purpose?

Comment: I always have this problem!  The `\onslide` solution doesn't always work with `align` (in amsmath) either.  Sometimes I simply can't get incremental equations at all, for no apparent reason.  Would be nice to hear an analysis of what's going on.

Comment: Works fine with me (Win 7,TeXnicCenter 2,MikTeX 2.9). `\documentclass{beamer}\usepackage{amsmath}\begin{document}\frame{\[y = 2x + \uncover<2->{3}\]}\end{document}`. Can you include the preamble of your document together with your TeX system (computer, TeX distribution etc.). And a side issue why not using `\[ y = 2x + \uncover<2->{3} \]` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer} %making it a slideshow
\author{Kaare Mikkelsen}
\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{Colors} 
\begin{equation*} y = 2x + \onslide<2->{3} \end{equation*} %the "3" will be shown one mouse-click later than "y=2x"
}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I think you should remove the `\usepackage{graphicx}` command?

Comment: I have edited it accordingly :)

Comment: @Kaare, Hi, what if I want to uncover `2`, which is not at the end of the equation?

Comment: @Kaare y = \onslide<2->{2}x + \onslide<3->{3}